# Corda dynamic data handling at the time creating a contract

Tags: corda

I am finding a solution to handle dynamic data / list to all nodes or specified nodes at the time creating a contract in Corda. I don’t think Oracle is a good approach to use in my case for the following reasons:

- The data can be a list of for example legal entity names, they are not from outside world, not a single value;
- The list is depended on particular field(s) selected, therefore will need perhaps a centralized place to maintain the data relationship;

Appreciate if anyone can help on this. Thanks.

Kwan

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little difficult to answer without further details on your use-case. However, on the surface, an Oracle doesn't sound like a bad solution:

1. The data provided by an oracle can be a list
2. The term "outside world" simply refers to any information not included in the transaction itself. This term should not be taken too literally.

Ultimately, you can think of an Oracle as a provider of "official" data. You request a command including the data from the oracle, include it in the transaction, and the oracle will sign over the transaction if and only if it agrees that the data in the command is true. As long as the Oracle is trusted by all parties involved, this allows data from outside the transaction to be included in the transaction in a reliable way.

Comment: Thanks Joel. There will be the case to query data several time during the contract creation and the return data is depended on the previous selection. For example, the contract types depends on the participant I choose. Can Oracle be such dynamic?

Comment: By contract creation, do you mean when building a transaction, or during transaction verification? When building a transaction, you can just use a standard API, or pass the arguments into the flow.